# How do I boot from USB into New install without Keyb

Tags: boot, grub2, usb

Q: I want to install (again), having slip - kicked the PS/2 connector, left me without keyboard.
How do I set USB as 1st boot device? It has Ubuntu image set up.

Yet, I can not press <kbd>DEL</kbd> or <kbd>F</kbd> Keys.

So,...

Grub?
What is the easiest way to run install from USB live image?
Or, maybe a program to start like `wubi.exe` ?

My system is running: (and functional)

```
ev1@persephone:~$ uname -a
Linux persephone 4.4.0-121-generic #145-Ubuntu SMP Fri Apr 13 13:47:23 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: https://www.wikihow.com/Reset-Your-BIOS

Comment: SOLUTION: Accessibility Settings || Go to people you know, get USB keyboard. And also Screen Keyboard in Accessibility settings.
Yet, how influence Boot Menu without keyb. (Q) remains.